# Диаризация спикеров в wav-файле, но я не знаю заранее их количество

Tags: python

Я уже долго ищу,

pyAudioAnalysis требует знать кол-во спикеров заранее.
pydiar работает только с 2 спикерами.
И много моделей посмотрел, там то лицензию нужно одобрять, то нужно заранее знать сколько людей.

Кто то знает вариант, желательно хоть с какой то документацией?

Comment: подсчитай количество стульев в кабинете